# skip: registration vs remove :registerable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Suppose I want to create a model User without self registration.
I have created the User model and added the following line

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

in my `routes.db` file I skip registration

```
devise_for :users, skip: :registrations
```

When I run `rake routes` registration paths disappear.

However, I can get the same configuration simply removing `:registerable` from the User model instead of adding `skip: :registrations.

So the question: what is the main difference between the two ways of removing self-registration? Which one is more preferable?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are not interested in user registration, both options give you the same result, although I prefer to remove the `registerable` module from the User model to avoid loading it and not use it at all.

You can see the `devise` method in the next link, so you can understand what you're avoiding by not loading the module:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models.rb#L77

On the other hand, if you are interested in user registration through any subclass (say buyer or seller, using STI) not the class itself (user), you need the `registerable` module on User model and something like that on routes:

```
devise_for :users, skip: :registrations
devise_for :buyers, only: :registrations
devise_for :sellers, only: :registrations
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks!!! For example, if I don't want users to be able to register themselves then the best choice is simply remove the `registerable` module.

Answer (score 1):

There can be other reasons for wanting to remove the registration routes - eg. making your own routes that point to the Devise controllers.

If you really want to disable site registration, then remove `:registerable` from your User model.